# JGrowl set theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jgrowl

My Jgrowl code is:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.jGrowl("<strong>Error!</strong><br />An invalid ID was passed and your template could not be loaded", { sticky: true, theme: 'test' });
    });
```

And my CSS in the Jgrowl CSS is:

```
.test{
    background-color:       #000000;
}
```

But it's not applying that CSS to the box.  I'm probably misusing the theme option, but am struggling to find much documentation on it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The .test background-color is overridden by the "div.jGrowl div.jGrowl-notification" style.
You could make the .test style !important:

```
.test{
    background-color:       #000000 !important;
}
```

or access the .test class more specifically like so:

```
"div.jGrowl div.jGrowl-notification.ui-state-test"
```

this will override it too

Answer (score 2):

You can use the parameter of Configuration Options of **jGrowl**

**theme** is a CSS class designating custom styling for this particular message, intended for use with jQuery UI.

CSS:

```
.jGrowl .changeCount {
    background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

JS:

```
$.jGrowl("Message in box", {theme: 'changeCount'});
```

More information about this plugin here:
https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl/blob/master/README.md